# BootstrapVue Unknown word Error in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

i would like to use bootstrap vue with my own scss file for theming.

Unfortunately I always get a strange error:

```js
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                    
error  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss

Syntax Error: SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | // --- BootstrapVue Custom SCSS ---
    | ^
  2 | 
  3 | // Requires at least the Bootstrap functions, variables and



 @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./src/assets/custom.scss 4:40-286
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--6-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.20:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

For the structure I followed exactly the docs

My custom.scss File:

```js
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #51ff00,
  "danger": #ff4136
);

@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

and the main.js File:

```js
// ***** Bootstrap Vue *****

import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import './assets/custom.scss'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
```

I'm using the recommended Versions of

"bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
"sass": "^1.32.13",
"sass-loader": "^10.2.0"

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I accidentally imported my custom.scss file into my app.vue additionally

```js
<style>
@import 'assets/custom.scss';
</style>
```